# How to calculate co-ordinates of rectangle if I know one co-ordinate size and angle of rotation?

Tags: c++, qt, rotation, resize, qgraphicsitem

I come up with a problem while rotating and resizing qgraphicsitem when it is rotated. I am drawing two qgraphicsitems one to resize inner qgraphicsitem. When I rotate inner item that time I want to find all co-ordinates of inner(rotated) item, but when I rotate it I only get scenePos() of this item and no other points i.e. it gives me topLeft points. As shown in image [image]

I want to find all dark circled points of the item. These both items are added on the scene.

Comment: Could you not use trig to find these values?

Comment: yeah but how could i use trig, what are the formula's can you please explain it

Comment: It's not completely clear: Do you have the point connecting `T` & `L` or the top left point of the white square?

Comment: I have all points of white item, size and rotation of gray item and angle between L and T

Comment: **angle** between L & T? isn't the gray item a rectangle (forcing that angle to be 90)? Maybe you're referring to the angle between T and the white shape's top edge?

Comment: @AbhijeetBhilare There's a right triangle in each corner. You know the hypotenuse and the angles, so finding the other two sides is straightforward.

Comment: Oh sorry I have coordinate point between L and T and and angle of rotation of gray item

Comment: could you please tell me how could I find the co-odinates from this?

Comment: Why can't you get the local coordinates of the item and map them to the scene with QGraphicsItem::mapToScene? http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#mapToScene-6

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Is this method useful to find all cords including (height,width) of gray item?

Comment: It gives me same cords as sceneBoundingRect of gray Item and those are same as white item

Comment: Does the class in question inherit from QGraphicsItem and you're drawing a rect in the paint function? Also, are you calling rotate, or rotating the painter in the paint function in order to rotate the item. Note that showing your code would really have helped your question!

Answer (score 0):

Use `QTransform`. Something like this:

```
QTransform t;
t.rotate(angle);
QPolygon polygon = t.mapToPolygon(rect)
```

Comment: I am not getting exact rect when I use above method . I passed rect as t.mapToPolygon(QRect(QPoint(regFrame->scenePos()), QSize(regFrame->boundingRect().size())));

Comment: Well, the result of this method is not a rect - it's a polygon, which consits of points. Hint from help: `Polygons and rectangles behave slightly differently when transformed (due to integer rounding), so matrix.map(QPolygon(rectangle)) is not always the same as matrix.mapToPolygon(rectangle).`

Answer (score 0):

Without code shown in the question, I'm going to assume that you have a class that inherits from QGraphicsItem and you're painting a rectangle in the paint function.

This means that you're returning the bounding rect of the item in its appropriate [boundingRect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect) function.

As you've probably discovered, the bounding rect will not rotate with the rotation of the item.

If you implement the [shape](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#shape) function, you'll be able to call it to retrieve the points of the polygon via [QPainter::toFillPolygon](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#toFillPolygon) passing in the item's current transform.